# How to define click event separately for each path element

Tags: android, svg, android-vectordrawable

I am working with SVG files on Android. Android Studio converts SVG files into XML files containing vector and path elements. An XML file can have multiple "path" elements. The problem starts right here. I want to give each path element the ability to be individually clicked without using webview. (Cause of javascript is **risky**!) Is there a way to do that?

I cant use clicked pixels colors. Cause they are very variable. 
I can seperate each path elements to different XML files. But this paths also keep remember of where they are located. And when I wanted to add each XML files into FrameLayout, they are expanding their rectangle edge untill to the phone edge. Even if they have wrap_content in width and height properties.. So onClick events blocked. onClick events works just one. You can check blue edge in the photo. This blue edge same for each imageviews :

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/path_one" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/path_two" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/path_three" />
</FrameLayout>
```

path_one :

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="800dp"
    android:height="340dp"
    android:viewportHeight="340"
    android:viewportWidth="800">
    <path
        android:fillAlpha="1"
        android:fillColor="#da241c"
        android:pathData="M52.39,44.01L54.63,41.94L57.68,42.54L64.66,41.57L66.41,42.87L67.51,45.88L72.34,49.65L75.51,48.5L78.38,45.54L80.04,39.15L82.2,37.29L88.55,34.96L92.09,34.57L100.5,29.58L100.87,28.25L102.52,28.39L102.52,28.39L103.01,29L103.01,29L99.86,44.65L97.47,48.72L97.49,51.15L95.74,54.66L95.58,57.53L96.47,59.49L96.47,59.49L94.92,62.8L91.57,62.71L86.49,60.02L76.48,62.25L74.69,65.68L74.09,69.27L69.49,73.59L67.58,77.44L62.61,81.12L57.04,82.69L54.94,84.99L52.22,85.67L52.22,85.67L52.17,82.72L55.49,74.92L52.38,73.87L46.42,74.15L46.42,74.15L42.46,68.99L43.56,60.73L41.5,58.83L42.36,57.78L46.69,57.12L50.78,53.06L53.17,48.89z"
        android:strokeAlpha="1"
        android:strokeColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:strokeWidth="0.5" />
</vector>
```

path_two :

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="800dp"
    android:height="340dp"
    android:viewportHeight="340"
    android:viewportWidth="800">
    <path
        android:fillAlpha="1"
        android:fillColor="#da241c"
        android:pathData="M65.51,0.31L67.29,0.43L69.07,2.54L70.31,2.65L71.46,5.52L74.69,8.09L76.36,8.08L78.5,11.11L79.06,9.29L80.72,9.11L81.02,8.09L83.07,8.3L84.16,7.07L89.81,8.73L89.13,6.6L90.46,5.69L90.65,6.31L90.81,5.52L92.95,7.36L95.64,6.4L97.64,6.94L98.86,12.3L96.42,12.11L95.82,15.36L98.39,21.01L100.86,24.08L100.16,24.76L100.66,26.19L102.52,28.39L102.52,28.39L100.87,28.25L100.5,29.58L92.09,34.57L88.55,34.96L82.2,37.29L80.04,39.15L78.38,45.54L75.51,48.5L72.34,49.65L67.51,45.88L66.41,42.87L64.66,41.57L57.68,42.54L54.63,41.94L52.39,44.01L52.39,44.01L51.05,42.86L52.28,40.45L51.14,36.11L53.41,32.2L53.03,30.73L55.21,27.9L54.06,26.81L52.37,28.67L51.38,27.75L53.83,24.46L53.44,21.65L54.99,18.26L53.52,15.1L53.8,5.66L53.8,5.66L54.44,3.71L56.24,2.68L56.19,1.3L58.01,0.66L63.53,2.51L63.5,1.29z"
        android:strokeAlpha="1"
        android:strokeColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:strokeWidth="0.5" />
</vector>
```

path_three :

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="800dp"
    android:height="340dp"
    android:viewportHeight="340"
    android:viewportWidth="800">

    <path
        android:fillAlpha="1"
        android:fillColor="#ea912d"
        android:pathData="M149.16,48.24l13.17,3.21l0.97,-0.56l9.4,2.24l3.93,-0.05l0,0l0.09,2.6l-2.37,3.93l-1.63,0.55l-4.18,-0.92l-2.36,3.82l-3.88,-1l-3.13,0.58l-7.01,8.76l0,0l-1.03,-0.72l-2.56,0.6l1.22,-2.52l-5.9,-2.58l-1.44,-2.14L138.81,62l-0.64,-2.35l1.87,-1.48l0.64,-2.98l1.15,-0.78L140.88,53l0.69,-1.95l3.24,-2.5L149.16,48.24zM103.83,29.47l3.97,4.12l14.47,7.7l2.63,0.46l11.03,5.02l5.3,0.2l1.37,0.79l-0.02,1.47l-3.03,3.02l1.39,1.77l-3.64,6.48l-5.6,1.74l-0.73,0.96l-2.9,-1.3l-5.83,1.08l-1.03,-0.66l-0.32,-2.42l-0.93,-0.04l-1,1.8l-5.09,-3.12l-7.7,-1.98l-6.57,1.16l-3.11,1.77l0,0l-0.9,-1.97l0.17,-2.87l1.74,-3.51l-0.02,-2.43l2.39,-4.07L103.01,29l0,0L103.83,29.47z"
        android:strokeAlpha="1"
        android:strokeColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:strokeWidth="0.5" />
</vector>
```

All of them together :

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="800dp"
    android:height="340dp"
    android:viewportHeight="340"
    android:viewportWidth="800">
    <path
        android:fillAlpha="1"
        android:fillColor="#da241c"
        android:pathData="M52.39,44.01L54.63,41.94L57.68,42.54L64.66,41.57L66.41,42.87L67.51,45.88L72.34,49.65L75.51,48.5L78.38,45.54L80.04,39.15L82.2,37.29L88.55,34.96L92.09,34.57L100.5,29.58L100.87,28.25L102.52,28.39L102.52,28.39L103.01,29L103.01,29L99.86,44.65L97.47,48.72L97.49,51.15L95.74,54.66L95.58,57.53L96.47,59.49L96.47,59.49L94.92,62.8L91.57,62.71L86.49,60.02L76.48,62.25L74.69,65.68L74.09,69.27L69.49,73.59L67.58,77.44L62.61,81.12L57.04,82.69L54.94,84.99L52.22,85.67L52.22,85.67L52.17,82.72L55.49,74.92L52.38,73.87L46.42,74.15L46.42,74.15L42.46,68.99L43.56,60.73L41.5,58.83L42.36,57.78L46.69,57.12L50.78,53.06L53.17,48.89z"
        android:strokeAlpha="1"
        android:strokeColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:strokeWidth="0.5" />

    <path
        android:fillAlpha="1"
        android:fillColor="#da241c"
        android:pathData="M65.51,0.31L67.29,0.43L69.07,2.54L70.31,2.65L71.46,5.52L74.69,8.09L76.36,8.08L78.5,11.11L79.06,9.29L80.72,9.11L81.02,8.09L83.07,8.3L84.16,7.07L89.81,8.73L89.13,6.6L90.46,5.69L90.65,6.31L90.81,5.52L92.95,7.36L95.64,6.4L97.64,6.94L98.86,12.3L96.42,12.11L95.82,15.36L98.39,21.01L100.86,24.08L100.16,24.76L100.66,26.19L102.52,28.39L102.52,28.39L100.87,28.25L100.5,29.58L92.09,34.57L88.55,34.96L82.2,37.29L80.04,39.15L78.38,45.54L75.51,48.5L72.34,49.65L67.51,45.88L66.41,42.87L64.66,41.57L57.68,42.54L54.63,41.94L52.39,44.01L52.39,44.01L51.05,42.86L52.28,40.45L51.14,36.11L53.41,32.2L53.03,30.73L55.21,27.9L54.06,26.81L52.37,28.67L51.38,27.75L53.83,24.46L53.44,21.65L54.99,18.26L53.52,15.1L53.8,5.66L53.8,5.66L54.44,3.71L56.24,2.68L56.19,1.3L58.01,0.66L63.53,2.51L63.5,1.29z"
        android:strokeAlpha="1"
        android:strokeColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:strokeWidth="0.5" />

    <path
        android:fillAlpha="1"
        android:fillColor="#ea912d"
        android:pathData="M149.16,48.24l13.17,3.21l0.97,-0.56l9.4,2.24l3.93,-0.05l0,0l0.09,2.6l-2.37,3.93l-1.63,0.55l-4.18,-0.92l-2.36,3.82l-3.88,-1l-3.13,0.58l-7.01,8.76l0,0l-1.03,-0.72l-2.56,0.6l1.22,-2.52l-5.9,-2.58l-1.44,-2.14L138.81,62l-0.64,-2.35l1.87,-1.48l0.64,-2.98l1.15,-0.78L140.88,53l0.69,-1.95l3.24,-2.5L149.16,48.24zM103.83,29.47l3.97,4.12l14.47,7.7l2.63,0.46l11.03,5.02l5.3,0.2l1.37,0.79l-0.02,1.47l-3.03,3.02l1.39,1.77l-3.64,6.48l-5.6,1.74l-0.73,0.96l-2.9,-1.3l-5.83,1.08l-1.03,-0.66l-0.32,-2.42l-0.93,-0.04l-1,1.8l-5.09,-3.12l-7.7,-1.98l-6.57,1.16l-3.11,1.77l0,0l-0.9,-1.97l0.17,-2.87l1.74,-3.51l-0.02,-2.43l2.39,-4.07L103.01,29l0,0L103.83,29.47z"
        android:strokeAlpha="1"
        android:strokeColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:strokeWidth="0.5" />
</vector>
```

Comment: have you got answer?

Answer (score 7):

You can use RichPath library, it has an integrated OnClickListener which passes clicked path element. GitHub link: https://github.com/tarek360/RichPath

Define SVG as VectorDrawable and add it to XML

```
 <com.richpath.RichPathView
    android:id="@+id/ic_notifications"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:vector="@drawable/ic_notifications" />
```

And set setOnPathClickListener in code:

```
richPathView.setOnPathClickListener(new RichPath.OnPathClickListener() {
 @Override
public void onClick(RichPath richPath) {
   if (richPath.getName().equals("path_name")) {
       //TODO do an action when a specific path is clicked.
   }
 }
});
```

Comment: is there a way to add zooming functionality to RichPathView?

Comment: I suggest you to look into https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view if you need zooming functionality.

Comment: ok thank you, and does this library also support path click detection like richpath does?

Comment: Nope, this library uses PNG raster images.

Comment: well, that's the case for me. I have to combine zooming svg and detect which path was clicked, is it possible to do in Android?

Comment: In my use case I hardcoded image paths in coordinates and used a fixed PNG image.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, there is no way to achieve what you want using VectorDrawables.  I think you are probably going to have to load the SVG into a WebView.

However you don't have to use any JavaScript.  The WebView widget has a way to intercept link requests.  See [Handling Page Navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#HandlingNavigation]) in the WebView documentation.

You would just need to surround your `<path>` elements with a `<a>` link element.

```
<svg ...etc...>
    <a xlink:href="SOME_URL">
        <path d="..."/>
    </a>
    ....
</svg>
```

Then intercept "SOME_URL", whatever it is, in your `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` method.

Answer (score 0):

If you seperate all paths into different ImageView-s, than you can override all of the IV's onTouchListener like this:

```
firstImg.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getDrawingCache());
        int color = bmp.getPixel((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY());
        if (color == Color.TRANSPARENT)
            return false;
        else {
            // here you can handle your click event
            return true;
        }
    }
});
```

But be careful, this approach uses a LOT of resources because every touch event goes through several onTouch listeners.